# Redirecting to /sitecore/admin/LDAPLogin.aspx and Forcing Login

Tags: active-directory-module

We are having some issues with Active Directory and redirecting to the `/sitecore/admin/LDAPLogin.aspx` page.

What should be properly setup so users are redirected to this page to login? Also just to confirm this is the correct page? The goal is to have it redirect to an HTTPS (secured login).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using the AD module for some time now and here are some items for consideration.

1. The `LDAPLogin.aspx` page could be substituted for the `/sitecore/login/default.aspx` in the event you want all users to use AD.
2. I recommend you make the entire site HTTPS for Content Authors, that way there is no special setup for the login page.

There is a post [here](http://www.nehemiahj.com/2013/01/how-to-enable-single-sign-on-in-sitecore.html) that provides a more detailed example as to which files to rename.